# users and who return no usernames

Tags: openvpn, coreutils

Strange thing happened today. I went to look up who was currently logged in on a box using the users command and it returned nothing. It didn't even return my username. The particulars are below. I am trying to determine if this is a bug or some configuration issue. I have never had a situation where "users" didn't just work. I did just install OpenVPN, so maybe that has something to do with it. I looked on another, un-updated Ubuntu (maybe a month since last update) and it shows users.  Any ideas why users doesn't seem to work anymore? Does `/var/run/utmp` get encrypted by OpenVPN?

```
richmaes@portal02:/var/log/openvpn$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS \n \l

richmaes@portal02:/var/log/openvpn$ uname -a
Linux portal02 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
richmaes@portal02:/var/log/openvpn$ users
richmaes@portal02:/var/log/openvpn$ who
richmaes@portal02:/var/log/openvpn$ whoami
richmaes
```

UPDATE:  I took a automated software update and now users and who reports that I am logged in to the machine, however; it will not report other users.  I have checked to verify that other users can connect to the platform and when they run users, they see that I am logged in, however they do not see their username returned.  Does anyone know what the escalation path is for a coreutils Ubuntu bug?

Comment: Sorry only thing I can think of asking is check paths and check environment. But now got the WHO stuck in my head now. They aren't the worst band to get stuck in your head. You welcome 

Comment: Are  `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` world-readable (mode `644`, ` -rw-r--r--`?

Comment: Those files are world readable.
`richmaes@portal01:/etc$ ls -lart /etc/group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1266 Mar  1 09:14 /etc/group
richmaes@portal01:/etc$ ls -lart /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2777 Feb  7 15:45 /etc/passwd`